# Ошибка в dll (использование Java Native Interface)

Tags: javafx, dll, jni

С помощью Visual Studio делаю dll для JavaFX приложения. Получилось реализовать в dll простую функцию сложения двух чисел. Но при работе со строками Visual Studio ругается: ***"Выражение должно иметь тип указателя"*** (ошибка с выражением (*env)->...)

Реализацию данной функции взял из учебника без изменений:

[image: в]
Вот код .cpp файла:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "application_Main.h"

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_application_Main_getLine
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring prompt) {
    char buf[128];
    const jbyte *str;
    str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, prompt, NULL);
    if (str == NULL) {
        return NULL; /* OutOfMemoryError already thrown */
    }
    printf("%s", str);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, prompt, str);
    /* We assume here that the user does not type more than
    * 127 characters */
    scanf("%s", buf);
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, buf);
}
```

Вот код .h файла:

```
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class application_Main */

#ifndef _Included_application_Main
#define _Included_application_Main
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     application_Main
 * Method:    getLine
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_application_Main_getLine
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Если определен typedef **__cplusplus** то **env** представляет собой структуру. 
В этом случае нужно использовать так называемый *"с++ стиль"* :

```
env->GetStringUTFChars(prompt, NULL);
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(prompt, str);
env->NewStringUTF(buf);
```

В противном случае нужно использовать *"с стиль"* :

```
(*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, prompt, NULL);
(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, prompt, str);
(*env)->NewStringUTF(env, buf);
```

В данном случае typedef **__cplusplus** определен, поэтому ошибка при попытке обратиться к структуре **env** как к указателю